# g++ / vscode apparently cannot see my src folder? "cc1plus.exe: fatal error: src/glad.c No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, g++, glfw

(Before someone mentions similar questions with the same issue, yes I have checked my path for spaces and whatnot. Heres my path to the project root: `C:\Users\sircode\Documents\GitHub\Univox\` So Im not sure what else could be causing it)

Title says the gist of it. Im trying to get a purely VSCode c++ / opengl project running, but Ive been struggling to get g++ to see the files via my `tasks.json` file.

My args in the tasks file are as such:

```json
"args": [
    "-g",
    "-std=c++17",
    "-I./include",
    "-L./lib",
    "src/\\*.cpp",
    "src/glad.c",
    "-lglfw3dll",
    "-o",
    "${workspaceFolder}/prog.exe"
],
```

When I try to click the `Run C/C++ File` task, it fails to run and fires these errors into the console:

```bash
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -g -std=c++17 -I./include -L./lib src/\*.cpp src/glad.c -lglfw3dll -o C:\Users\sircode\Documents\GitHub\Univox/prog.exe
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: src/\*.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
cc1plus.exe: fatal error: src/glad.c: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

My folder structure should work with that command but it just doesnt, and I have absolutely no clue why. Ive attempted appending a parent / project root reference (../ and ./) to the folder paths with no luck.

I dont know if Im just missing something really obvious here, but Im out of ideas.

Heres my project structure:

[image]

Comment: It probably should be `"${workspaceFolder}/src/glad.c",`

Comment: I agree get rid of the \\ and use `"${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp",`

Comment: Same issue, `src/*.cpp: No such file or directory`, same thing with glad.c. Ill try the workspace folder one

Comment: @drescherjm okay, so I added ${workspaceFolder} to both links and it works. It caused a minor issue with the include and lib folder, but I replaced the "." after I and L with ${workspaceFolder} and the program launched successfully. Thankyou. If you wanna post it as an answer I could approve it so you get some rep for it

Comment: Working args adjusted as such: "-I${workspaceFolder}/include", "-L${workspaceFolder}/lib", "${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp", "${workspaceFolder}/src/glad.c",

Comment: Worth learning an actual build system at this point.

Comment: @sweenish wdym? Do you mind explaining further?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the simple quick answer by Drescherjm.

I was simply missing "${workspaceFolder}" from all the references. Not sure why the original guide was missing that.

The include and lib folder were also broken after fixing the initial src folder, but the same solution applies to them.

Working args adjusted for the include, lib, and src folders:

```json
"args": [
    "-g",
    "-std=c++17",
    "-I${workspaceFolder}/include",
    "-L${workspaceFolder}/lib",
    "${workspaceFolder}/src/*.cpp",
    "${workspaceFolder}/src/glad.c",
    "-lglfw3dll",
    "-o",
    "${workspaceFolder}/prog.exe"
],
```

Comment: Strange, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right, it's not necessary. The official guides show `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"` but the OP did not post a [mcve] of tasks.json.

Comment: The build command used to cd ${workspaceFolder} first but I can see from the output in the question that this didn't happen. Edit: The comment above makes sense.